# How can delete cookie which is created with rack-affiliates gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I am using [rack-affiliates gem](https://github.com/alexlevin/rack-affiliates) for invite feature in rails project. I can create cookies but I can not delete created cookie. I am using rails cookie delete method in [these api codes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) for delete process but it does not work. How can delete cookie which is created with rack-affiliates gem in rails?

Thanks for advices.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the cookie like you would any other?  cookies.delete :cookie_name_here

Comment: @bkunzi01  thanks for answer. I solved this problem. I was forget specify cookie path.